# Enemy sprite will not flip left

Tags: python, animation, pygame, sprite

I have a sprite that traverses left and right using the following function below. When it flips left, it flips the img for 1 frame it seems and then stays pointing right while moving left. Same 1 frame flip happens at the other side too. With a single image this works fine, but I have added this animation loop in and now I am stumped.

```py
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):#==================================================
    def __init__(self,x,y):   
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.images_right = []
        self.frame_index = 0
        self.counter = 0
        for num in range (1,8):
            img_right = pygame.image.load(f'img/enemy/{num}.png')   
            self.images_right.append(img_right)
        self.image = self.images_right[self.frame_index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.move_direction = 1
        self.move_counter = 0

    def update(self):
        self.counter += 1
        walk_cooldown = 2
        if self.counter > walk_cooldown:
            self.counter = 0
            self.frame_index += 1
            if self.frame_index >= len(self.images_right):
                self.frame_index = 0
            self.image = self.images_right[self.frame_index]
        self.rect.x += self.move_direction
        self.move_counter += 1
        if abs(self.move_counter) > 32:
            self.move_direction *= -1
            self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, True, False)  
            self.move_counter *= -1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a list of images. You're only flipping the last image in the list.

In the constructor, create a list of right and left images and select the image to be displayed in `update`:

[image]

```py
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):   
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        
        self.images_right = [pygame.image.load(f'img/enemy/{num}.png') for num in range (1,8)]
        self.images_left = [pygame.transform.flip(img, True, False) for img in self.images_right]
        
        self.frame_index = 0
        self.image = self.images_right[self.frame_index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))   
        self.counter = 0
        self.move_direction = 1
        self.move_counter = 0

    def update(self):
        self.counter += 1
        walk_cooldown = 2
        if self.counter > walk_cooldown:
            self.counter = 0
            self.frame_index += 1
            if self.frame_index >= len(self.images_right):
                self.frame_index = 0
        self.rect.x += self.move_direction
        self.move_counter += 1
        if abs(self.move_counter) > 32:
            self.move_direction *= -1
            self.move_counter *= -1

        image_list = self.images_right if self.move_direction > 0 else self.images_left    
        self.image = image_list[self.frame_index]
```

Comment: Many, many thanks! Tried to do this myself before I copied this, but to no avail :( Will note this method to apply in future!

Comment: @Matt You know that you can accept answers? This will mark them as solved. Do so if the answer solved your question. This can also be done to your older questions that you have gotten an answer to, if they helped you solve your issue.